# Not able to change the icon in recyclerview android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, icons

I am developing one small app in which i have set a notification whenever user click on the notification icon image in the recyclerview the notification will trigger at the same time i want to replace the notification icon with notification start icon.

Again if the user click on the notification start icon i want to change the icon to notification stop icon.

Kindly let us know how can i achieve this .Thanks for your help!!!

Please find the below screenshots and code for the same.

1) Screenshot of recyclerview while starting the app

[image]

2) I want to change the icon to Notification start icon if the user click on the notification icon for the first time.

[image]

3)Again if the user click on the notification start icon i want to change the icon to notification stop icon

[image]

1) Recyclerview xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="65dp"
android:elevation="10dp"
android:background="#E0F2F1"
android:orientation="horizontal"
tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute">

<ImageView
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:id="@+id/listIcon"
   android:tint="#FF5722"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_adjust_black_24dp"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
<TextView
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:id="@+id/item_name"
    android:textSize="17dp"
    android:text="Dummy text"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:fontFamily="Roboto Regular"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText,SpUsage" />
<ImageView
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:id="@+id/listIcon1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_notifications_off_black_24dp"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription,RtlHardcoded" />


</LinearLayout>
```

2) Recyclerview Adapter

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends     RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ItemHolder> {

Context c;
ArrayList<Habits> habits;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
TextView textItemName;
ImageView imageView, imageView1;
FragmentManager fm;
private ItemCLickCallBack itemCLickCallBack;
EditText Remainder;
Time t = new Time();

public interface ItemCLickCallBack {
    void onItemClick();
}

public void setItemCLickCallBack(final ItemCLickCallBack itemCLickCallBack) {
    this.itemCLickCallBack = itemCLickCallBack;
}


public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Habits> habits) {
    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.habits = habits;
    this.c = context;
}

@Override
public RecyclerViewAdapter.ItemHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_item, parent, false);
    return new ItemHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerViewAdapter.ItemHolder holder, int position) {

    final Habits item = habits.get(position);
    holder.textItemName.setText(item.getName());
    textItemName = (TextView) holder.textItemName.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
    imageView = (ImageView) holder.imageView.findViewById(R.id.listIcon1);

    holder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View v, final int pos) {

            if (v.getId() == textItemName.getId()) {
                Intent i = new Intent(c, SecondActivity.class);
                c.startActivity(i);

            }
            if (v.getId() == imageView.getId()) {

                LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(c);
                View dialogView = li.inflate(R.layout.edit_dialogue, null);
                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        c);
                alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Edit Your Habit");
                alertDialogBuilder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_edit_black_18dp);
                alertDialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);
                final EditText EdiTime = (EditText) dialogView
                        .findViewById(R.id.editTime);
                final EditText EditHabit = (EditText) dialogView
                        .findViewById(R.id.edithabit);
                final EditText Remainder = (EditText) dialogView.
                        findViewById(R.id.interval);
                Remainder.setText(item.getInterval());
                EditHabit.setText((CharSequence) item.getName());
                EdiTime.setText(editTimeText());

                EdiTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        final Calendar mcurrentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
                        int hour = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                        int minute = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

                        TimePickerDialog mTimePicker;
                        mTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(c, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                            @Override

                            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int hour, int minute) {

                                mcurrentTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
                                mcurrentTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
                                Intent intent = new Intent(c, Notification_reciever.class);
                                intent.putExtra("HABIT_KEY",item.getName());
                                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(c, 100, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                                AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) c.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                                alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, mcurrentTime.getTimeInMillis(),Integer.parseInt(Remainder.getText().toString())*60*1000, pendingIntent);
                            }
                        }, hour, minute, false);


                        mTimePicker.setTitle("Select Time");
                        mTimePicker.show();


                    }
                });



                alertDialogBuilder
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("SAVE",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                        int id) {
                                        update(item.getId(), EditHabit.getText().toString(), t.getHour(), t.getMinute(), Remainder.getText().toString());

                                        itemCLickCallBack.onItemClick();
                                    }
                                })
                        .setNegativeButton("DELETE",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                        int id) {
                                        delete(item.getId());
                                        itemCLickCallBack.onItemClick();
                                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                                        dialog.cancel();

                                    }
                                });
                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                alertDialog.show();

            }

        }


    });


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return habits.size();
}

class ItemHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    private ImageView imageView, imageView1;
    private TextView textItemName;
    ItemClickListener itemClickListener;


    public ItemHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textItemName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
        imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.listIcon1);
        imageView.setOnClickListener(this);
        textItemName.setOnClickListener(this);

    }


    public void setItemClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        this.itemClickListener.onItemClick(v, getLayoutPosition());

    }


}

private void update(int id, String name, int hour, int minute, String interval) {
    DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(c);
    db.openDB();
    long result = db.update(id, name, hour, minute, interval);

    if (result > 0) {
        Toast.makeText(c, "Saved successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(c, "failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    db.closeDB();

}

private void delete(int id) {
    DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(c);
    db.openDB();
    long result = db.delete(id);
    db.closeDB();

    if (result > 0) {
        Toast.makeText(c, "Deleted successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you try calling `setImageResource` or similar methods that change the image from your imageView inside your `if (v.getId() == imageView.getId()) {`?

Comment: Yes, I did since the view are getting recycled again old icon(notification icon) is coming but i want Notification start icon